# Getting error while trying to use react speech recognition module in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, speech-recognition

I am trying to implement speech recognition into my next.js website. I downloaded and am trying to use the same code from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition) link, but I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-speech-recognition\lib\RecognitionManager.js:247:61
    at C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-speech-recognition\lib\RecognitionManager.js:332:6
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-speech-recognition\lib\RecognitionManager.js:452:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\client\node_modules\react-speech-recognition\lib\SpeechRecognition.js:16:50)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because I followed the instructions of the npm download website I linked above. Here is my code:

```
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Product = () => {
  const {
    transcript,
    listening,
    resetTranscript,
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
  } = useSpeechRecognition();

  // Handle browser support error
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>;
  }

  return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
          <div style={styles.speechTitle}>Talk to us, tell us about your day...</div>
          <div style={styles.speechBox}>

          </div>
          <button onClick={() => console.log('hello')}>Hello</button>
          <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
          <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
          <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
          <p>{transcript}</p>
      </div>

  );
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's at the bottom of the docs - under Troubleshooting.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition

> `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`
>
> If you see the error
> `regeneratorRuntime is not defined` when using this library, you will
> need to ensure your web app installs `regenerator-runtime`:
>
> - `npm i --save regenerator-runtime`
> - If you are using NextJS, put this at the top of your `_app.js` file:
>   `import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'`. For any other framework, put
>   it at the top of your `index.js file`

Comment: Super happy I found this. Thanks! Works for nextjs `v14`

Comment: so glad it's helped - thanks for the info on nextjs 14 compatibility. Will remember this when I (finally) upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M83t.png)It is can fix by  import 'regenerator-runtime' at the top of files importing SpeechRecognition

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35751303)